# How to send jquery value into coldfusion variable <CFSET> to perform <CFQUERY>?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

on mouseenter I want to send the jquery value to cfset variable to perform cfquery in second page

```
//---first page---
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".div5").mouseenter('contextmenu2', function (hr) {
    var id = this.id;
    var trd = $("#hover_id").val(id);  
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'jobdetail.cfc?method=job1',
      data: { jobdt: "#trd#"}
    });
  });
});
```

```
<!--- jobdetail.cfc page --->
<cffunction name="job1" output="false" access="remote" returntype="string">
  <cfargument name="jobdt" required="true" type="any"/>
  <cfquery name="jd" datasource="xxxx">
    SELECT * 
    FROM xxxxx
    WHERE xxx='xx' 
      AND xxx= <cfqueryparam value='#arguments.jobdt#' cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" />  
  </cfquery>
  <cfreturn "OK" />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Use `{jobdt: trd}` instead of `{jobdt: "#trd#"}`

Comment: Also, `var id = this.id;var trd = $("#hover_id").val(id);` this looks wrong.

Comment: .. specifically [$("#hover_id").val(id)](https://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) attempts to *assign* the value of `id` to `$("#hover_id")`. Perhaps you meant to use `$("#hover_id").val()`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `trd` is a javascript variable, not a ColdFusion variable, you don't need to use # signs within the jQuery. To pass that value, use `data: { jobdt: trd }` instead of `data: { jobdt: "#trd#" }`.

The above code is for a single value. If you want to pass more than one value, such as a "name" and "id":

```
var name = 'kannan' ;
var id = 10

$.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'jobdetail.cfc?method=job1',
      data: { "name": name, "id" : id }
});
```

If you want to send more arguments, you can do it by using `JSON.Stringify()`:

```
var data = {};
// You can select your form value here also ( $('selector).val() )
data["Name"] = "Kannan"; 
data["id"] = "10";
data["address"] = "Kovilpatti india";
// ... etc
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "jobdetail.cfc?method=job1",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    error: function( msg ){
        // do something on error
        console.log( msg );
    },
    success: function (data) {
        // do something on success
        console.log( data );
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually, I want to send 'id' to cfset variable...
       <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#d1").mouseenter(function (e) {
             var id = this.id;
             .ajax({
                type:'POST',
        url:'jobdetail.cfc?jobdt=' + id,
        data: { jobdt: 'id'}
                   });
             });
         })
      </script>

<!--jobdetail.cfm-->
       <cfset var1 = url.jobbt>
          <cfquery>  
              select XXX......
           </cfquery>

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there was some problem in POST. Now, I have solved it.thanks